# Reduce finishing delay of VsCode task when called by "dependsOn"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There is like a 500ms delay after completion of a task before running the next.

Are there any ways to reduce/remove this delay?

It can easily be tested by the pasting the following into `tasks.json` and run the task `echo4`

```
        {
            "label": "echo1",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo 1",
        },
        {
            "label": "echo2",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo 2",
            "dependsOn": "echo1",
        },
        {
            "label": "echo3",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo 3",
            "dependsOn": "echo2",
        },
        {
            "label": "echo4",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo 4",
            "dependsOn": "echo3",
        },
```

Comment: Have you tried chaining a sleep command? Something like "echo 3; sleep 0.5"